# ValueError: Floating point image RGB values must be in the 0..1 range. while using matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, deep-learning, pytorch

I want to visualize weights of the layer of a neural network. I'm using pytorch.

```
import torch
import torchvision.models as models
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def plot_kernels(tensor, num_cols=6):
    if not tensor.ndim==4:
        raise Exception("assumes a 4D tensor")
    if not tensor.shape[-1]==3:
        raise Exception("last dim needs to be 3 to plot")
    num_kernels = tensor.shape[0]
    num_rows = 1+ num_kernels // num_cols
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(num_cols,num_rows))
    for i in range(tensor.shape[0]):
        ax1 = fig.add_subplot(num_rows,num_cols,i+1)
        ax1.imshow(tensor[i])
        ax1.axis('off')
        ax1.set_xticklabels([])
        ax1.set_yticklabels([])

    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.1, hspace=0.1)
    plt.show()
vgg = models.vgg16(pretrained=True)
mm = vgg.double()
filters = mm.modules
body_model = [i for i in mm.children()][0]
layer1 = body_model[0]
tensor = layer1.weight.data.numpy()
plot_kernels(tensor)
```

The above gives this error `ValueError: Floating point image RGB values must be in the 0..1 range.`

My question is should I normalize and take absolute value of the weights to overcome this error or is there anyother way ? 
If I normalize and use absolute value I think the meaning of the graphs change.

```
[[[[ 0.02240197 -1.22057354 -0.55051649]
   [-0.50310904  0.00891289  0.15427093]
   [ 0.42360783 -0.23392732 -0.56789106]]

  [[ 1.12248898  0.99013627  1.6526649 ]
   [ 1.09936976  2.39608836  1.83921957]
   [ 1.64557672  1.4093554   0.76332706]]

  [[ 0.26969245 -1.2997849  -0.64577204]
   [-1.88377869 -2.0100112  -1.43068039]
   [-0.44531786 -1.67845118 -1.33723605]]]


 [[[ 0.71286005  1.45265901  0.64986968]
   [ 0.75984162  1.8061738   1.06934202]
   [-0.08650422  0.83452386 -0.04468433]]

  [[-1.36591709 -2.01630116 -1.54488969]
   [-1.46221244 -2.5365622  -1.91758668]
   [-0.88827479 -1.59151018 -1.47308767]]

  [[ 0.93600738  0.98174071  1.12213969]
   [ 1.03908169  0.83749604  1.09565806]
   [ 0.71188802  0.85773659  0.86840987]]]


 [[[-0.48592842  0.2971966   1.3365227 ]
   [ 0.47920835 -0.18186836  0.59673625]
   [-0.81358945  1.23862112  0.13635623]]

  [[-0.75361633 -1.074965    0.70477796]
   [ 1.24439156 -1.53563368 -1.03012812]
   [ 0.97597247  0.83084011 -1.81764793]]

  [[-0.80762428 -0.62829626  1.37428832]
   [ 1.01448071 -0.81775147 -0.41943246]
   [ 1.02848887  1.39178836 -1.36779451]]]


 ..., 
 [[[ 1.28134537 -0.00482408  0.71610934]
   [ 0.95264435 -0.09291686 -0.28001019]
   [ 1.34494913  0.64477581  0.96984017]]

  [[-0.34442815 -1.40002513  1.66856039]
   [-2.21281362 -3.24513769 -1.17751861]
   [-0.93520379 -1.99811196  0.72937071]]

  [[ 0.63388056 -0.17022935  2.06905985]
   [-0.7285465  -1.24722099  0.30488953]
   [ 0.24900314 -0.19559766  1.45432627]]]


 [[[-0.80684513  2.1764245  -0.73765725]
   [-1.35886598  1.71875226 -1.73327696]
   [-0.75233924  2.14700699 -0.71064663]]

  [[-0.79627383  2.21598244 -0.57396138]
   [-1.81044972  1.88310981 -1.63758397]
   [-0.6589964   2.013237   -0.48532376]]

  [[-0.3710472   1.4949851  -0.30245575]
   [-1.25448656  1.20453358 -1.29454732]
   [-0.56755757  1.30994892 -0.39370224]]]


 [[[-0.67361742 -3.69201088 -1.23768616]
   [ 3.12674141  1.70414758 -1.76272404]
   [-0.22565465  1.66484773  1.38172317]]

  [[ 0.28095332 -2.03035069  0.69989491]
   [ 1.97936332  1.76992691 -1.09842575]
   [-2.22433758  0.52577412  0.18292744]]

  [[ 0.48471382 -1.1984663   1.57565165]
   [ 1.09911084  1.31910467 -0.51982772]
   [-2.76202297 -0.47073677  0.03936549]]]]
```

Comment: What floating point values are you using at the moment?  You failed to display the offending vector.

Comment: I added the offending vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds as if you already know your values are not in that range.  Yes, you must re-scale them to the range 0.0 - 1.0.  I suggest that you want to retain visibility of negative vs positive, but that you let 0.5 be your new "neutral" point.  Scale such that current 0.0 values map to 0.5, and your most extreme value (largest magnitude) scale to 0.0 (if negative) or 1.0 (if positive).

---

Thanks for the vectors.  It looks like your values are in the range -2.25 to +2.0.  I suggest a rescaling `new = (1/(2*2.25)) * old + 0.5`

Comment: There are still negative numbers

Comment: What value maps to a negative number?  You need to key to the value with the largest magnitude (absolute value).  I see now that there's a `-3.69201088` in the list.  Alter the re-scaling divisor (2.25) accordingly.

Comment: the `np.max(filter)` is returning `4.189.....` but there's no such number. This is the max value `3.12674141` That's so strange.

Comment: Even after scaling there are negative values.

Comment: Ah ... double the scaling divisor.  My mistake.  I updated the equation, although still using the old -2.25 value.

Comment: Thank you @Prune. Your answer helped me immensely. :)