# After converting from rgb to lab it is raising issue by matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, anaconda, scikit-image

I converted an RGB image into `lab` by this command:

```
im_lab=skimage.color.rgb2lab(im, illuminant='D65', observer='2')
```

However, once I am sending to my algorithm to segment and then show through `matplotlib.pyplot`, I am receiving the following error (it is a long error but this the last part):

```
/home/xxx/anaconda2/envs/lda-nv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cm.pyc in to_rgba(self, x, alpha, bytes, norm)
    255                 if xx.dtype.kind == 'f':
    256                     if norm and xx.max() > 1 or xx.min() < 0:
--> 257                         raise ValueError("Floating point image RGB values "
    258                                          "must be in the 0..1 range.")
    259                     if bytes:

ValueError: Floating point image RGB values must be in the 0..1 range.

<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x7f14e4dfa990>
```

this the part of code which is calling matplotlib:

```
# displaying the result
    fig = plt.figure()
    a = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
    plt.imshow(in_image)
    a.set_title('Original Image')
    a = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)
    print(output.shape)
    plt.imshow(skimage.color.lab2rgb(output,illuminant='D65', observer='2'))
    a.set_title('Segmented Image')
    plt.show()
```

can someone please help me to find out what is the reason and how can I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Convert it back to RGB(A) before plotting... that's what pyplot is expecting.

Comment: I converted by skimage, however I am still getting error, that is why I posted here. Thanks for your comment

Comment: Could you post the output of `lab2rgb`'s shape, min, max and dtype, please?

Answer (score 0):

According to a post I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47318871/valueerror-floating-point-image-rgb-values-must-be-in-the-0-1-range-while-usi) it seems that after segmentation you are getting negative values which are popping up like this as problem.

Solution that is posted on it seems to be

```
Value<0 equate the value to 0
```

Solution seems to have worked check the link above if it helps you too