# Artistic Style Transfer : ValueError: Floating point image RGB values must be in the 0..1 range. using pytorch

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch

### Problem

I work on a subject of "artistic transfer", and I want to transfer style of the image Style to content of Image content - but I get this error instead.

erreur :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d26b5592f0b4> in <module>()
    113         plt.imshow(imcnvt(target),label="Epoch "+str(i))
    114         plt.show()
--> 115         plt.imsave(str(i)+'.png',imcnvt(target),format='png')

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/cm.py in to_rgba(self, x, alpha, bytes, norm)
    224                 if xx.dtype.kind == 'f':
    225                     if norm and (xx.max() > 1 or xx.min() < 0):
--> 226                         raise ValueError("Floating point image RGB values "
    227                                          "must be in the 0..1 range.")
    228                     if bytes:

ValueError: Floating point image RGB values must be in the 0..1 range.
```

`ValueError: Floating point image RGB values must be in the 0..1 range.`

and I cannot resolve this error.

I have tried using `content = np.abs(content)` but it gives an output very far from the expected result.

I'm using pytorch. thank you!

---

### Codes

```
import torch 
from torchvision import transforms , models 
from PIL import Image 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

device = ("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")


model = models.vgg19(pretrained=True).features
for p in model.parameters():
    p.requires_grad = False
model.to(device)

def model_activations(input,model):
    layers = {
    '0' : 'conv1_1',
    '5' : 'conv2_1',
    '10': 'conv3_1',
    '19': 'conv4_1',
    '21': 'conv4_2',
    '28': 'conv5_1'
    }
    features = {}
    x = input
    x = x.unsqueeze(0)
    for name,layer in model._modules.items():
        x = layer(x)
        if name in layers:
            features[layers[name]] = x 
    
    return features

transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(300),
                              transforms.ToTensor(),
                              transforms.Normalize((0.5,0.5,0.5),(0.5,0.5,0.5))])


content = Image.open("/mama.jpg").convert("RGB")
content = transform(content).to(device)
print("Content shape => ", content.shape)
style = Image.open("/picasso.jpg").convert("RGB")
style = transform(style).to(device)

def imcnvt(image):
    x = image.to("cpu").clone().detach().numpy().squeeze()
    x = x.transpose(1,2,0)
    x = x*np.array((0.5,0.5,0.5)) + np.array((0.5,0.5,0.5))
    return x

fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)

ax1.imshow(imcnvt(content),label = "Content")
ax2.imshow(imcnvt(style),label = "Style")
plt.show()

def gram_matrix(imgfeature):
    _,d,h,w = imgfeature.size()
    imgfeature = imgfeature.view(d,h*w)
    gram_mat = torch.mm(imgfeature,imgfeature.t())
    
    return gram_mat


target = content.clone().requires_grad_(True).to(device)

#set device to cuda if available
print("device = ",device)


style_features = model_activations(style,model)
content_features = model_activations(content,model)

style_wt_meas = {"conv1_1" : 1.0, 
                 "conv2_1" : 0.8,
                 "conv3_1" : 0.4,
                 "conv4_1" : 0.2,
                 "conv5_1" : 0.1}

style_grams = {layer:gram_matrix(style_features[layer]) for layer in style_features}

content_wt = 100
style_wt = 1e8

print_after = 500
epochs = 4000
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([target],lr=0.007)

for i in range(1,epochs+1):
    target_features = model_activations(target,model)
    content_loss = torch.mean((content_features['conv4_2']-target_features['conv4_2'])**2)

    style_loss = 0
    for layer in style_wt_meas:
        style_gram = style_grams[layer]
        target_gram = target_features[layer]
        _,d,w,h = target_gram.shape
        target_gram = gram_matrix(target_gram)

        style_loss += (style_wt_meas[layer]*torch.mean((target_gram-style_gram)**2))/d*w*h
    
    total_loss = content_wt*content_loss + style_wt*style_loss 
    
    if i%10==0:       
        print("epoch ",i," ", total_loss)
    
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    total_loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    
    if i%print_after == 0:
        plt.imshow(imcnvt(target),label="Epoch "+str(i))
        plt.show()
        plt.imsave(str(i)+'.png',imcnvt(target),format='png')
```

Comment: Can you paste the full error? in which line you're getting it?

Comment: the fully error have been posted; thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: Floating point image RGB values must be in the 0..1 range. while using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47318871/valueerror-floating-point-image-rgb-values-must-be-in-the-0-1-range-while-usi)

Comment: I have traying this solution, but it donsn't work ! same error persist